# React Navigation, how to make Stack Navigation inside Tab navigation in v6?

Tags: react-native, stack-navigator, tabnavigator, react-native-tabnavigator, react-navigation-v6

I'm trying to make a Tab navigation with "homepage", "profile" & "search", and inside "home" Screen, make a stack navigation with "more details" & "wishlist". I'm currently in react-navigation v6 and I'm trying like so :

```js
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const StackNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Homepage" component={Homepage} />
      <Stack.Screen name="MoreDetails" component={MoreDetails} />
      <Stack.Screen name="WishList" component={WishList} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}

export default App(){
  <NavigationContainer>
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Search" component={Search} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Homepage" component={StackNavigator} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
}
```

So When you click on "homepage", you have a button to go to "moreDetails" and on this page you have a button to go to "wishlist".

What Am I doing wrong ? According to docs, it seems to be like that.
Your help would be awesome !

Answer (score 0):

All good, sorry for asking..
In v6 it's not `npm i @react-navigation/stack` but `npm i @react-navigation/native-stack`
and `import { createNativeStackNavigator }`
it's working now. Hope it can help someone later.

Answer (score 0):

maybe is because you forget to import the screens

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).